# Set new sectionHeaderTopPadding property for different sections in iOS 15

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios15

Is it possible to adjust the new section header top padding property for table views per section? You can adjust it for all sections like this, but I would like to have some sections be `0` and other sections the default padding in a table view.

```
self.tableView.sectionHeaderTopPadding = 0;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use heightForHeaderInSection delegate method:

Documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614855-tableview

Comment: I tried that, but it increases the height of the entire section. There doesn't seem to be a way to adjust the new section padding property in iOS 15 per section while keeping the default height.

Comment: Can you share your code?